# not able to add prefix on session value, it is fine on localhost

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

```
    $newid = 'asktguyjttyyu';
                  if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
                    session_name(SESSION_NAME);
                    session_start();
                    }
                  $newid = session_create_id($newid.'-');
                  $_SESSION['expire_time'] = 30*60;
                  session_commit();
                  ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
                  session_id($newid);
                  session_start();
```

```
I need to add prefix in session value , for that i am using session_create_id(). It is working fine on local host but when i upload it on godaddy server it has stopped working, it seems that server is not able to recognize session_create_id() and other session related function e.g. session_start() are working fine there.
```

I have also checked the php version on server it is 7.2.

I have no idea why it is not working, Can someone please help me out?

Comment: session_create_id() is not working on server

Comment: So what exactly is happening? Do you have any errors in the log? Or is your application behaving in an unexpected way? How did you determine that `session_create_id` is the problem?